# How can i set full width to JTextArea?

Tags: java, jtextarea

How can i set full width to JTextArea?
I tried to get the maximum possible size of JTextArea, and set it, but its just do a JTextArea smaller.

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(10, ?);
```

Comment: it depends on the layout you use.

Answer (score 4):

You should not do this explicitly. The best way to achieve this is to use correct layout manager. If for example you put text area to the center of `BorderLayout` it will get the maximal size:

```
Panel p = new Panel();
p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
p.add(new TextArea(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: That's what i approximately did, but its shown in minimum size.

`Panel p = new Panel(); p.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); JScrollPane scrollingArea = new JScrollPane(new JTextArea()); add(scrollingArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);`

Answer (score 2):

You have to put the JTextArea in a JScrollPane.

Here's a working example.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SimpleFrame implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JScroll Pane Test");

        JTextArea txtNotes = new JTextArea();
        txtNotes.setText("Hello World");
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(txtNotes);
        frame.add(scrollPane);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new SimpleFrame());
    }

}
```